# What's the Rails.root equivalent in a Rack application?

Tags: rack

I'm familiar with the `Rails.root` in Rails which tells you the directory of your current application.  This is quite handy sometimes.

Now I'm developing a Rack application (on which Rails is based).  How do I find out the `Rails.root` equivalent for a Rack application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This returns the root directory in a string.

```
Rack::Directory.new('').root
```

Not sure if there's a better, shorter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is a simple `File.expand_path`:

```
File.expand_path(File.join("log", "some_file_#{ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development"}.log"))
```