# Gem shared between Rails and Sinatra applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sinatra

I'm writing a gem of my own which is shared between a Sinatra app and a Rails app.

The gem generates a logger which will write to a default location - "/log/[logger_name]" in the project root directory.
My problem is that I have no way of computing the project root directory which will be common between both apps.

Is there a way to compute the path which the project is running from, regardless of if it's a Rails or Sinatra app? Is there an elegant way to solve it without using a regex?

Comment: You can try `Dir.pwd` to get current working directory of a project. But I would solve this problem by treating differently Rails and Sinatra - `Rails.root` for rails and `settings.root` for Sinatra. Just check if `Rails::VERSION` is defined - if so, use rails way, otherwise - Sinatra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both Rails and Sinatra are based on Rack, I would try to get the project root directory with [`Rack::Directory.new('').root`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22861228) and join it with logger file's relative path.

```
project_root = Rack::Directory.new('').root
logger_path = Pathname.new(project_root).join('log/production.log')
```